# share authenticated user in whole app spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am trying to build an application where users can post products.
Database looks like this :

```
user     
--------
username
password
```

```
product
-------
name
price
idUser
```

I try to use spring security 6. So far I managed to succeed subscription, login, logout and filters.

The problem is when I try to post a new product I can't find a way to set the user ID.

UserController :

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/add_product")
    public String addProduct(@Validated @ModelAttribute("product") ProductDto productDto,
                             @AuthenticationPrincipal User user)
    {
        User userConnected = userRepository.findOneByIdUser(user.getIdUser());
        productDto.setUser(userConnected);
        productService.save(productDto);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Form (which is reachable only if authenticated) :

```
<form th:action="@{/add_product}" th:object="${product}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Titre" th:field="*{name}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Prix" th:field="*{price}">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
</form>
```

SpringSecurity :

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/subscribe").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/add_product").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                    .loginPage("/")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/?error")
                    .permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
                    .permitAll()
            );
     return http.build();
}
```

The error I get when I post the form :

```
Cannot invoke "com.project.mesi.entity.User.getIdUser()" because "user" is null
at com.project.mesi.controller.UserController.addProduct(UserController.java:101)
```

The thing I do not understand is that I can display the name of the authenticated user on homepage with HTML navbar thymeleaf fragment but when I go on the add product page the user is null (it says "Hello null !")

```
<li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <p class="nav-link text-body m-0" th:text="'Hello' + ${user} + ' !'"></p>
</li>
```

The user seems to be null no matter what I have tried, like instantiate:

`Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

which do the trick when the username needs to be displayd on homepage.

I also tried to cast `auth.getPrincipal();` to my User entity but that is a no go.

Now my questions are: is there a way to share the authenticated user through the whole application? Is there something I am doing wrong here? Please ask if you need more infos. Thank you in advance

Comment: Try using `@AuthenticationPrincipal(errorOnInvalidType=true) User user`. That should give you an error most likely that the principal is not of the class `User`, but some other class.

Comment: Hi @WimDeblauwe and thank you for your answer. You are right it isn't the class `User` which is expected but another one , in my case it is `UserDetails`. If my understanding of Spring Security is good, the expected class of `@AuthenticationPrincipal` is defined in the SpringSecurityConfig class, am I right ?